# Highcharts nearest point tooltip not show due to undefined series

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

On the previous question I've asked awhile ago
[Highchart tooltip show nearest point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28848146/highchart-tooltip-show-nearest-point)

I just noticed there is a weird problem happens when implementing the bubble or scatter chart. The chart display correctly but the tooltip won't show, open the console log and mouse hover around the chart and the follow error occurs

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'series' of undefined
```

I tried to solve it by detect if chart variable is undefined then do process anything but it still doesn't work.

JSfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ittikorns/ygscLp3h/1/

Comment: How would you expect this to work anyway though? You have one series and an unordered series type. How do you want it to function?

Comment: The error comes from the `arguments[1]` (aka `point`) not being an array, but a single point, since there is no shared tooltip and it is an unordered series type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described by **@Halvor Strand**, you have just one point, so you should be using shared option. However, it won't work, because Highcharts forces scatter and bubble series to use non-shared tooltip.

Instead, very helpful method `Highcharts.splat()` will make an array (with just one point) in case when you have an object, take a look: https://jsfiddle.net/o6drjwef/ - the good thing is that `splat()` doesn't change anything if an array is passed as an argument.

Snippet:

```
points = Highcharts.splat(args[1]),
```